# How to change an html paragraph text based on selected radio button?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, modal-dialog

I have been developing a course management system with PHP and MySQL. I recently ran into a problem. I created a basic webpage (`EditCompletion.php`). Basically, what I want to do, is have a link on that page that opens a jQuery Modal Window and within that modal window should be 3 radio buttons, a small description paragraph (which changes when a new radio button is clicked), and a submit button. This is how I want it to work:

I want to be able to select a student (`CERTAIN SELECTED STUDENT`) and a lesson (`CERTAIN SELECTED LESSON`) then I want to be able to click the link on EditCompletion.php that then opens the jQuery Modal Window. I want to then be able to choose from the following options:

```
Unlock - (Description Paragraph - Are you sure your want to unlock (CERTAIN SELECTED LESSON) for (CERTAIN SELECTED STUDENT))?

Exempt - (Description Paragraph - Are you sure you want to exempt (CERTAIN SELECTED STUDENT) from (CERTAIN SELECTED LESSON))?

Master - (Description Paragraph - Are you sure you want to master (CERTAIN SELECTED STUDENT) out of (CERTAIN SELECTED LESSON))?
```

`THE CERTAIN SELECTED` will show up as the `CURRENT SELECTED [WHATEVER]`. For example, `SELECT STUDENT JOHN DOE` and `LESSON 1` on `EditCompletion.php` and then click the link to open the modal. I want to select an option using radio buttons, and upon clicking "save", the MySQL database would be updated.

Comment: This post needs some serious formatting.

Comment: @Jeremy1026: And volume control.

Comment: I tried fixing it up a bit, but it's very difficult to tell which parts are db queries, and which ones are just all caps (yet another valid reason for raising caps lock awareness on the Internet).

Comment: No need to post smart alec remarks. I was trying to be as clear as possible when posting this. I just need some help. That is all.

Comment: It's not smart aleck. You really shouldn't use unnecessary, scream-like all-caps when asking about a language which performs about 2/3 of its operations using unnecessary, scream-like all-caps.

Comment: This question doesn't look like it's to do with php or mysql, right?  It looks like a jquery/javascript question.

Comment: Magic answer: FOREACH, SQL QUERIES (SELECT, UPDATE), HEADER and some functions in light way This question is too complex for answering in one wizard action!

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
<?php 
            for($samples as $sample){
        echo '<a onclick="return (confirm(\'..message here.. for '.$sample['name']. 'about'.$sample['lesson'].'\'))? true: false;">Action</a>';

            }
        ?>
```